# issue in Cypher query with exclusion

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm facing issue with Cypher query exclusion.

i want to exclude Article which are linked to an Article with the propertie TypeArticle <> CA.

I always encounter with wrong Article classified in CA as TypeArticle

But if i do the same thing like i want to find Article linked to Article with the propertie TypeArticle = CA, it works.

The exclusion doesn't work. 1 and 2

1

```
MATCH (n:Article {TypeArticle: 'PF', ArticleStatut:'20' , ETB:'CLM'})-->(m:Article)
WHERE m.TypeArticle<>"CA"
return DISTINCT n
```

2

```
MATCH (n:Article {TypeArticle: 'PF', ArticleStatut:'20' , ETB:'CLM'})-->(m:Article)
WHERE NOT TypeArticle="CA"
return DISTINCT n
```

**BUT this work**

```
MATCH (n:Article {TypeArticle: 'PF', ArticleStatut:'20' , ETB:'CLM'})-->(m:Article)
WHERE m.TypeArticle="CA"
return DISTINCT n
```

I think i missed something

Thanks for your help, i need this for an Use case in my company...

Vincent

Comment: Hello ! Thanks a lot for your help, that works ! i understand now

Answer (score 0):

By not working I assume you mean doesn't return any results... It looks like your article has no relationships with other articles that don't have this exact type of article. If you want to find articles that don't have a relationship to a specific article type, you can try:

```
MATCH (n:Article {TypeArticle: 'PF', ArticleStatut:'20' , ETB:'CLM'})
WHERE NOT (n)-->(:Article{TypeArticle:"CA"})
return n
```

Comment: You have a syntax error, and `DISTINCT` is not needed.